# typescript requireJS hitting recursive load error - from a new call

Tags: requirejs, typescript

This only occurs in our application which is a ton of code and not something I can put up, nor something anyone would be willing to slog through. So all I can do is describe the error.

We are building our typescript with --amd and have a ton of recursive references between files. It all is working fine until I put this one call in a function:

```
var di = new moduleDocIterator.DocIterator(null);
```

With this, the initial load of the main .ts (.js actually) file gives me the null or undefined reference exception on setting up __extends at the top of the generated .js file.

Both the file this call is in and the file moduleDocIterator references have nothing static in them except a couple of strings. The generated .js creates the object for each class but nothing that looks like it is actually executing.

And none of this code is called at the time this happens. This is just the initial load of everything asked for via requireJS.

How do I figure out why it's unhappy?

Comment: I've noticed when the typescript compiler generates a `define` statement it only includes imports that have been *used* in the module.  It sounds like adding the `var di = new moduleDocIterator...` line is causing the moduleDocIterator import to be considered *used* which means it's appearing in the `define` statement's array of dependencies, and maybe this is a circular reference or perhaps there's a problem downloading the file (check fiddler)?

Comment: I think @JeremyDanyow is correct: TypeScript's compiler will drop/ignore AMD dependencies that are ``import x = require('x')`` when x is never used (you have to ``/// <amd-dependency path="x" />`` to force a dependency that isn't used directly). It does seem likely that adding the line in question is when it finally added the AMD dependency. You can debug this by looking at the generated JS and examining the compiled ``define(['amddep', 'amddep2'], ...)`` output before/after the change.